# Get LaTeX symbols in Seaborn plots without messing up Pandas queries

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I construct a `DataFrame` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [0, 1, 0, 1],
    "y": [1, 2, 1.5, 3],
    "sigma": [1, 1, 2, 2],
})
```

It supports the nice `query` feature:

```
# OK!
pts = df.query("sigma < 2")
print(pts)
```

and plots:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="sigma", legend="full")
plt.show()
```

But I realize I would prefer the LaTeX symbol `\sigma` instead of the word "sigma" in the legend. Matplotlib can render it. I try instead:

```
SIGMA = "$\\sigma$"
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [0, 1, 0, 1],
    "y": [1, 2, 1.5, 3],
    SIGMA: [1, 1, 2, 2],
})
plt.clf()
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue=SIGMA, legend="full")
plt.show()
```

The plotting still works. But now if I try the query:

```
# Fails!
pts = df.query(SIGMA + " < 2")
print(pts)
```

I get an error message in the `pandas` query engine:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 28, in <module>
    pts = df.query(SIGMA + " < 2")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3184, in query
    res = self.eval(expr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3300, in eval
    return _eval(expr, inplace=inplace, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/eval.py", line 322, in eval
    parsed_expr = Expr(expr, engine=engine, parser=parser, env=env, truediv=truediv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py", line 827, in __init__
    self.terms = self.parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py", line 844, in parse
    return self._visitor.visit(self.expr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py", line 437, in visit
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py", line 431, in visit
    node = ast.fix_missing_locations(ast.parse(clean))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    $\sigma $<2 
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any way to:

1. Assign a different "display name" to the column that gets used in plots, but not for queries, or
2. Escape the LaTeX string appropriately so the Pandas query engine can handle it?

I would prefer 1. if possible, because it will make the queries look a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You could do your plot like this:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df.rename({"sigma": SIGMA}, axis=1), x="x", y="y", hue=SIGMA, legend="full")
```

This renames the column to `SIGMA` before passing it to the plot function, so what the plot function sees is a column called `"$\\sigma$"`.

`rename` by default returns a copy of the original DataFrame without modifying the original, so this lets you use the DataFrame normally with the column `"sigma"` in other contexts.  A downside, however, is that creating the new DataFrame could impact performance if the data is large.  In that case, you could write a function which renames the column in-place, does the plot, and then restores the name at the end.  It's often not a bad idea to write a custom function which encapsulates various tweaks you may want to incorporate into the plot without sullying the actual data.